# ASP.NET MVC3: Confirmation Box before submitting

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code which basically is a checkbox that causes a submit to take place.
As the task gets deleted for the DB, it is a requirement that some box comes up and says, "are you sure" or the likes, to confirm deletion.

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Complete", "Tasks", 
                                           new { TaskID = item.TaskID })'" />
```

This uses Razor syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.confirm) method:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Complete", "Tasks", new { TaskID = item.TaskID })'; }" />
```

or in a more unobtrusive way with jquery:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="complete" name="complete" data-url="@Url.Action("Complete", "Tasks", new { TaskID = item.TaskID })" />
```

and then in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#complete').click(function() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            window.location.href = $(this).data('url');
        }
    });
});
```

Also I would very strongly recommend you using another verb than GET on controller actions that modify state on your server such as marking a task as completed. PUT, POST and DELETE are good candidates. In your case since you are modifying an existing item the POST verb seems most natural.

Comment: Oh, Ive seen you added the Jquery way. Is this preferred and why? - What do you mean by unobtrusive. Also, How would I stop it being ticked. I thought it was straight forward, but i cant get it to work.

Comment: @Doomsknight, by unobtrusive it means that you are separating markup from script. As a consequence to this the size of your markup is smaller and results in less bandwidth consumption and your site is faster to load. Scripts are static resources that get cached on client browsers so they are served only once.

Comment: Cool, Ill go with Jquery then, guess its not as bad as I thought. What about not ticking it, if cancel is clicked? :)

Comment: @Doomsknight, you could test this as well: `if ($(this).is(':checked') && confirm('Are you sure?')) { ... }`.

Comment: Once its ticked it gets deleted, so thats not a problem, but if its checking and not doing anything, its rather confusing.

Comment: Unobtrusive means that your web site continues to work even if its user has no javascript enabled in his browser

Comment: Another problem Im experiencing with the JQuery method is that As this is part of a table, there are a few columns with id="complete" but only the Jscript works for the first one.

Comment: @Doomsknight, then apply a class to your checkboxes `class="complete"` and then use a class selector instead of id selector: `$('.complete').click...`. As far as checking/unchecking is concerned use the `$(this).is(':checked')` to determine whether the checkbox has been checked or not and adapt your if condition accordingly.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov. Your like a Guru! Thanks, youve greatly enhanced my knowledge of Javascripting and syntax practices. Id rather it didnt tick when I click cancel though. Suggestions on how to do this please?

Answer (score 4):

You may intercept the form submit event and ask confirmation. based on that return true or false to allow submit.
akin

```
 $("#form").submit(function (event) {


   if ( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete"))
       return true;
 else{
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;
      }
   });
```

Comment: I have several buttons `button type="submit"`, how do it, apply to only one button ?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done this way

```
<input name="button"  type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger cancel" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

hemant's solution didn't work for me. Moumit's solution did work but not when I moved the confirmation function to a named function in my page's javascript file - the confirmation button displayed but it was not prevented when I hit cancel (and as I write this, I wonder if I only needed to pass an event arg, call e.PreventDefault(), then return true).

Anyhow, here is yet another example, with a little help from JQuery, that did work in my aspnetcore mvc razor page:

```
$(function () {
    $('#mySaveButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            $('#myForm').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

I adapted this from a more complete example that is worked out from start to finish with an example project: [how to show a confirmation dialog with jquery](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37986.asp-net-core-how-to-show-a-confirmation-dialog-with-jquery.aspx)